# Slick carousel fade sticking with different sized images

Tags: jquery, slider, zurb-foundation, carousel, slick.js

I am trying to use the Slick carousel with the fade setting to display a slideshow of images for the front page of a website. The images in the slideshow are have two different size ratios (one for vertical images and another for horizontal). When the slideshow cycles from a larger to a smaller image, rather than fading smoothly, the excess width of the first image sticks and then disappears.

Here is a basic example of the code I'm using. You can see the result on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m4ug5o09/

HTML:

```
<div class="fade">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/900x400/000">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/700x400/">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.fade').slick({
dots: false,
infinite: true,
speed: 700,
autoplay: true,
fade: true,
autoplaySpeed: 3000,
arrows: false,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1});
```

Also, when I load the page, the initial image flashes real quickly at the bottom of the page (like in the footer).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if slick this problem can be resolved by tweaking slick settings. 
But there is a workaround if you are interested.

Add an id for the div containing the horizontal image.

```
<div>
  <img src="900x400.jpg"/>
</div>

<div id="horizontal">
  <img src="700x400.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Then in the css part mention something like this:

```
#horizontal
{
  background-color:white;
  width:900px;  // Width equal to the widest image in your slideshow
  height:700px;  // Height equal to the image of max height in your slideshow
}
```